# skimage ImageCollection and Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-image

I am having trouble using the skimage ImageCollection (http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#imagecollection) object in Python3. For example, in python 2,7, I was using it as follows:

```
import skimage.io as io

files = io.ImageCollection('/home/luca/sequence/*.*)
method_do_something(files[0])
```

This worked fine. When I use it in Python 3.4, the creation of the ImageCollection object works fine and len(files) returns the correct amount of files.

However, when I try the files[0] call, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

I was wondering if anyone knows of a workaround that might work on both 2.7 and python 3.x

Comment: This works perfectly on my system with the latest version of scikit-image.

Comment: I have the version 0.10 of skim age but have no access to the python3 at the moment. I will confirm it tomorrow.